# Iphone : How to return a image or anything from second view to first view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

please check the picture you will more clear what I want to present

This is the first launch in First View

It's an empty table view

There is a add button on the right bar

[image]

If you press the Add button it will push to the Second View

The second is a only 3 rows table view

[image]

Tap the first row it will pop up a alert view to let you set a name

[image]

Press create ,the text will appear in the first row

<**That's the question 1,I don't know how to pass the text to the cell...**>

And keep forward ,That's a custom radio button in the row 2 and row 3

Unless You click the radio button first , otherwise you can't call this methord

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

This is last two view
Icon View 1
[image]
Icon View 2
[image]

There are many buttons in the view,This the second question:
If I press one of this button,it will return to the second view and show the button icon on the tableview row 2 or row 3

Finally,press the Done button(same on the right bar)

It will back to the First View and show what you type the name , and which icon you selected 
(Basis on radio button is selected)

That's the last question.

I upload my source code here:[Link](http://www.sendspace.com/file/m5wju9)

You can download it ...

and here is the code about how I push the view...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row==0) {
        [self nameInputAlertView];
    }
    RadioButtonClass *btn = [radioButtonArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    if (btn.selected) {
        //Radio Button is selected ,use that icon 
        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            IconViewOne *iconViewOne = [[IconViewOne alloc]init];
            iconViewOne.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:iconViewOne animated:YES];
            [iconViewOne release];
        }
        if (indexPath.row==2) {
            IconViewTwo *iconViewTwo = [[IconViewTwo alloc]init];
            iconViewTwo.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:iconViewTwo animated:YES];
            [iconViewTwo release];
        }
    }
}
```

so...Summary all the question...

**1.How to write a text via textfield in the alert view to table view cell ?**

**2.How to selected an icon from last view to second view ?**

**3.Send all this two elements to First view : Name & Icon**

I only know how to pass elements from view 1 to view 2...
Don't know how to return back......

Thanks mate , please help me to figure out this problem.I will very very appreciate ！

BTW:you can take the radio button class to add in your any project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know this is the correct way or not but i think this may help you.
Since you want to retrieve the name and image in both views declare them in the appdelegate so that it can be accessed globally.

Que 1:

When selecting a row didSelectRow Delegate will be called. In that you will get the IndexPath. Store that indexPath globally. Then

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
if ([alertView tag]==1) {
    if (buttonIndex == 1){
        NSLog(@"Created");
        UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:tableIndexPath]; //tableIndexpath is declared globally as NSindexpath
        ReturnToFirstViewAppDelegate *appObj=(ReturnToFirstViewAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        appObj.selectedName = macroNameSetting.text; //Setting the Name globally
        cell.detailTextLabel.text =macroNameSetting.text;
        [self.tableView reloadInputViews];
    }
  }
}
```

Que 2 and 3

In the AppDelegate declare

```
NSString *selectedName;
UIImage *selectedImage;
```

Assign property and synthesize them

In your iconViews

```
- (void)setIcon : (id)sender{
  UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;
  UIImage *selectedImg = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"marco%d",button.tag]];
    ReturnToFirstViewAppDelegate *appObj=(ReturnToFirstViewAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    appObj.selectedImage = selectedImg;
// push your viewcontroller
 }
```

In any Viewcontroller access them as

```
  ReturnToFirstViewAppDelegate *appObj=(ReturnToFirstViewAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
 //For example
 //cell.image = appObj.selectedImage;
```

Comment: Thank you ! I'm looking your answer now ,I will try this soon.I vote your answer,It looks right.

Comment: I declare NSString *selectedName; in AppDelegate.h,but still got an error:Request for member "selectedName" in something not structure or union ?

Comment: sorry I forget #import "Appdelegate.h"

Comment: Oh..I have to add reload tableview,that will show the icon in the cell! almost finish it !keep going

Answer (score 1):

In any case if you dont like using AppDelegate Variables , there is one other method which You can use in case of Navigation Controllers :-

for eg. in "IConViewOne.m"

```
UITableViewCell* cell = [[[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]] ;
    cell.imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"marco%d.png",button.tag]];
```

and then in "ViewWillAppear" of SecondView :-

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Similarly for passing to RootViewController u can give:-

```
self.navigationController.topViewController.tableView
```

OR

```
[[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]tableView]
```

Comment: I think this is not finish yet...how can I save it ,if I finish editing , and leave the program , than back to it , still exist in the view ?

Comment: if u mean to say that u want to save that name and choosen icon ..u have to use somehting like "NSUserDefaults" or "Storing into Sqlite database"

Comment: i would recommend opening another question giving a link to this question ... so that u can get more answers from other members .. as u have already accepted the answer in this ..if u r not clear in what i have said in the above comment

Answer (score 0):

A great way to pass information from one object to another, without knowing who the recipient is (and there may be multiple objects interested in the information), is to post an NSNotification. It allows you to completely avoid direct knowledge of other objects.

Read Apple's document [Notification Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html) and give it a try.